# Jquery Data grid or flex datagrid

Tags: jquery, performance, datagrid

I have around 200,000 ( .2 million ) records in the database. Client wants at a time 5,000 records to be shown on the browser. I tried Jqgrid and loaded 5,000 records and for other records using pagination to load. But the scroll bar is taking some time to scroll and also sorting taking bit amount of time. To select a record it is taking pretty good amount of time ( even for 500 records to select a record taking considerable amount of time ). I tried this on Windows 7 62 bit machine and 8 GB ram. Browsers I tried are Firefox, IE and Chrome

I just checked Flex datagrid and it is loading pretty fast (since it is handled by flash player) and everything works perfectly.

But preference is for Jquery Grids. Are there any other grids you used that handles 5,000 records at a time at client end pretty fast (or is there any other way to increase performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) though I'm not sure that it will help you. The real problem here is that you want to show 5000 items on a page via javascript. What you should really do is tell you client its not practical and next to impossible and that you as the professional programer is telling him/her that the correct way to do it is to display the items 100 at a time and allow for searching and sorting

Comment: I have to completely agree here, your customer may want to have 5000 records on display at once, but the reality is that you will never be able to fit that many on one page. Hence, you use pagination and with pagination you can implement lazy loading of data (eg. data loading when it is needed). The important thing to realize in the end here as well is that it will not make a difference how you implement your datagrid as long as the solution works for customer.

Comment: Thanks @mcgrailm for your quick response and telling me about flexigrid , I see in tomorrows meeting what he says .

Comment: Thank you finally we are going with 500 records at a time . Still slow , but OK for client :)

Comment: sill overkill in my opinion. why would you want to look at that much data anyhow...oh well good luck

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of loading in 5000 records at a time, because you will never be displaying all 5000 records at once. Why don't you go for an options that buffers the next three pages worth of records from the current one. That way you are lazy loading the data, which is great because you avoid prolonged loading times and data that is not needed in the end if not fetched from the server.

Comment: Thanks @ZeSimon for your immediate response . I am going to meet client tomorrow and let me see what he says . Once again thanks

Comment: Thank you finally we are going with 500 records at a time . Still slow , but OK for client :)

Answer (score 0):

In my project server have more then 300000. client said to show all the record in same page with scroll-able and also some grid cells have editable. I am using devsbucket performance grid table. Its works great with editable, footer, active class, theme support.

This is the documentation and download link is [devsbucket grid table download](http://devsbucket.com/javascript/javascript-performance-grid-table/)